# Hls video blackout when bufferstallederror is raised

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have implemented Hls streaming library which is almost working fine but the problem is when I seek video forward the `bufferStalledError` is raised, and then screen blackouts until the segment is loaded. I have attached the fiddle link with this.
If your network is very fast please throttle it if you want to see the blackout.
I am not able to figure out how to do that. The ideal case should be the video should be processing at last frame processed, if the segment is loading.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jp6bx0a5/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause for this was I was trying to recover media using `hls.recoverMediaError();`. The Hls can handle itself what is expected.
So, removing the recovery code just worked for me.

Comment: @Abdishek No error handling just this: 

const hls = new Hls({ maxBufferSize: 320 * 1000 * 1000 });
hls.attachMedia(video);

hls.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
   hls.loadSource(streamUri);
 });

Comment: @Abdishek I've realized that this is happening only for a certain videos. Maybe something is wrong about transcoding. If you've an idea please share.